# Make event for a multiple buttons and know which button been clicked

Tags: asp.net, button, event-handling

I am writing an web app in asp.net,
In the code behind I have this code:

```
foreach(UserDetails _UD in m_TeachersDetailsList)     
{
  Button button = new Button();// a Button control
  button.Text = "click";
  button.ID = "SelectedTeacher";
  TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();// a Cell control
  tableCell.Controls.Add(button);
  TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
  tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell); // a table row
  TableSearchResult.Rows.Add(tableRow); // a table that had been created in the aspx 
}
```

How can I make an event that when you click on the button you go to a function,
and how can I know which button had been click and Brought me to my function.
thanks.

Comment: You trying to create multiple controls with same id, I don't think so it will work, did you try it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx should get you going...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this

```
 int id = 0;
 foreach(UserDetails _UD in m_TeachersDetailsList)     
 {
    Button button = new Button();// a Button control
    button.Text = "click";
    button.ID = "selectedTeacher" + id++;
    TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();// a Cell control
    tableCell.Controls.Add(button);
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell); // a table row
    TableSearchResult.Rows.Add(tableRow); // a table that had been created in the aspx 
    button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
 }
```

And common event handler

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This way you will get the button clicked
    Button button = (Button)sender;

}
```

**Important**

You will need to add the controls in `OnInit`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: the most important was the "Important" :). Must be placed in the init! I spent around 2 h trying to figure out why the hell is not working!!! Thx

Answer (score 1):

ASPX

```
asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click"
```

Codebehind

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button mybutton = (Button)sender;
    Response.Write(mybutton.ID);
}
```

Just use btn_Click as the onclick for each of your buttons. Then use the "sender" to determine which control sent the request.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the button's `id`, let it default. Set the button's `CommandArgument` property instead:

```
foreach (UserDetails _UD in m_TeachersDetailsList)     
{
  Button button = new Button();// a Button control
  button.Text = "click";
  button.CommandArgument = _UD.UserDetailID.ToString(); // some unique identifier

  // this is optional, if you need multiple actions for each UserDetail:
  button.CommandName = "SomeAction"; // optional

  button.Command += new EventHandler(detailButton_Handler);

  // ...etc...
}
```

Then your handler needs to check the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` values:

```
public void detailButton_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DetailID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    switch (e.CommandName.ToString())
    {
        case "SomeAction":
        /// Now you know which Detail they clicked on
            break;

        case "OtherAction":
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, `CommandArgument` is a much better solution (also, congrats on 10K =P)

Comment: @jadamel27: Thanks!! Gamification ftw!